# Android - retrofit array

Tags: java, android

this is my retrofit web service posting and receiving a string value

**MainActivity**

```
            Phone phone=new Phone();
            phone.phone=contactsString;
            WebService.getInstance().getApi().checkNumber(phone).enqueue(new Callback<MainResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<MainResponse> call, Response<MainResponse> response) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<MainResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                }
            });
```

**MainResponce.class**

```
public class MainResponse {
    @SerializedName("status")
    public int status;
    @SerializedName("message")
    public String message;
}
```

**Phone.class**

```
public class Phone {

    @SerializedName("phone")
    public String[] phone;
}
```

how to make this send an array of strings and receiving an array of string with no looping

Comment: can u explain your question?

Comment: I want to send a list of trings for example this mobileNumbes[] and receive another list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to change your Webservice To be able to get a list of phones and give you back a list of result and mention phone number in each result

Comment: and how is that?

Comment: If you are server side developer of this project just try to get a list of phone numbers as JSON and give back the result as JSON. the retrofit will make body as JSON

Comment: //your headers if needed
    @Headers({"Content-Type: application/json", "Accept: application/json”})
//your method if it is POST OR GET
    @POST(“your_service_URL”)
    Call<YourResponse> topUpWithScore(@Header("") ,@Body YourRequestObject req);

Comment: in your request send list of phones,  String[] phones = {"phone1","phone2"....}, and about response if it does not give you back list of results you should change server method

Answer (score 0):

as you writed, class phone include an array. you can easily send an instance of Phone class to server.